# Xamarin Forms HttpClient decide between two servers which one of them is up/active/responding

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

The scenario is this. On the company network, API URL is different and when accessed from the outside, it is different. So when the xamarin forms application starts, I need to test which of the two servers is responding to check whether it is the local network or the app is connected externally. This will be the deciding factor for which server to use for all other requests. Please note that the server is PHP based

Comment: A quick request to any resource and checking if `request.IsSuccessStatusCode` then do the same request to the second api endpoint won't do?

Comment: If the server is not accessible, the app keeps on waiting for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use James Montemagno's [Connectivity plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin) for this. You can check whether the device you are using is online and also use the `IsRemoteReachable` call to see if a server can be reached.

Also, ensure that all the proper rights required by the plugin are selected in the Android Manifest.

Comment: I'll test it and let you know how it goes

Comment: `IsReachable` is not working. Returns false for both servers whereas one of them is pinging in command line.

Comment: There is also the `IsRemoteReachable`, not sure what the difference is but you could try that as well. And note that pinging from the command-line is probably a different machine then your emulator/Simulator, so make sure that the host _is_ actually reachable from there as well.

Comment: `IsRemoteReachable` is also not working for some reason. Returns false for both servers

Comment: Sorry, My bad. I did not give the application the proper rights in the android manifest. Updated the answer as well. Thanks for all your help buddy.